# What's the best way for custom sort to NSMutableArray that contains objects

Tags: objective-c

I saw many examples for Custom sort for NSMutableArray , here one of them
[How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it), but I have an object with a and b, and I want to sort them according to a*b.

I saw this code for example

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"birthDate"
                                              ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

But I do not have birthDate here I need to sort according to a*b (both double)?

More details,

I have a NSMutableArray that contains CGRect objects, and I want to sort them according to width*height

Comment: What on earth is "a*b"?

Comment: you can add several sort descriptors if you want to sort by multiple parameters..

Comment: are you trying to sort the array by using date objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A NSSortDescriptor is not suitable for anything more complex than comparing a simple key, or possibly a set of keys.

You'll want to sort using a custom comparator (a block). Something like

```
sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    MyObject *first = (MyObject*)a;
    MyObject *second = (MyObject*)b;

    if (first.a * first.b < second.a * second.b) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if (first.a * first.b > second.a * second.b) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;
}]
```

Note I'm just winging it as far as your (a*b) description goes, not really sure what you want there.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the previous solutions. You can put CGRects in an array by wrapping them into an NSValue:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 10, 20, 30);
NSValue *valueToPutInArray = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect];
```

and sort them with a block like this:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [rectArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSValue *rectAValue, NSValue *rectBValue) {
        CGRect rectA = [rectAValue CGRectValue];
        CGRect rectB = [rectBValue CGRectValue];

        CGFloat areaA = rectA.size.width * rectA.size.height;
        CGFloat areaB = rectB.size.width * rectB.size.height;

        if (areaA < areaB)
        {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        }
        else if (areaB > areaA)
        {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        else
        {
            return NSOrderedSame;
        }
    }];
```

Another solution would be to wrap the CGRect into a custom object and add a function to it like

```
- (CGFloat)area
{
   return self.rect.size.width * self.rect.size.height;
}
```

(self.rect is the wrapped rect)
If you populate your array with those custom objects you can sort it with your original method by creating a sort descriptor like

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"area" ascending:YES];
```

This will simply compare the results of the area function and sort the array accruing to that.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to implement custom sorting is to use [`-[NSMutableArray sortUsingComparator:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-SW8) or [`-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW28).

```
sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    // Compare stuff, return a NSComparisonResult.
    return [obj1 compare:obj2];
}];
```

I like to explicitly pass the object types in the block, BTW. For example, for strings:

```
sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {
    // Compare stuff, return a NSComparisonResult.
    return [obj1 localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:obj2];
}];
```